# Inserting values into google sheets via apiv4 python

Tags: python, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I need help inserting values into sheets. this is what I have so far  basically the code that connects the system to google sheets API

```
from __future__ import print_function
import pickle
import os.path
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

# The ID and range of a sample spreadsheet.
SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID = 'some id '
SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME = 'Sheet1!A1:F3'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Sheets API.
    Prints values from a sample spreadsheet.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=726)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)



    sheet = service.spreadsheets()
    result = sheet.values().get(spreadsheetId=SAMPLE_SPREADSHEET_ID,
                                range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME).execute()
    values = result.get('values', [])

    if not values:
        print('No data found.')
    else:
        print('Name, Major:')
        for row in values:
            # Print columns A and E, which correspond to indices 0 and 4.
            print(row)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This code works it prints out the values in the sheet , this is basically what's written in the documentary. I'm having trouble with inserting values in the sheet.

I've scraped some info from a website and I need to throw the info in the sheet I'm not sure how to do that I tried to understand how updating values works in sheets but I kept getting errors in the code this is what i wrote

```
values = [
    [
        100, 300, 400 
    ],
    # Additional rows ...
]
body = {
    'values': values
}
result = service.spreadsheets().values().update(
    spreadsheetId=some id, range=SAMPLE_RANGE_NAME,
    valueInputOption='Raw', body=body).execute()
print('{0} cells updated.'.format(result.get('updatedCells')))
```

But it throws me a `pylint` error saying identation is not correct  on `[`  beside values

Can you tell me what I'm doing wrong or suggest a better way of inserting info into sheets I'd love to see examples

Comment: A `pylint` error is just a warning about your formatting and should not prevent the execution of your program. Please provide the error messages you're seeing.